# Mysql value lower than set

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set a new value for a column but the value is lower every time I try. Why?

```
UPDATE table SET active = 0
```

the field is empty

```
UPDATE table SET active = 1
```

sets the value to 0

```
UPDATE table SET active = 2
```

the value is 1

Structure: `active enum('0', '1', '2') utf8_unicode_ci  No  0`

Answer (score 2):

try wrapping it with single quote,

```
UPDATE table SET active = '2'
```

the query

```
UPDATE table SET active = 2
```

results `1` because `index value of 2` is **1**.

```
VALUE   INDEX
0        1
1        2
2        3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use smallint not enum data type.. 
Currently your enums are strings not int's so you must add ''